# Qt Creator - GUI from designer vs. GUI from code - how to access element's functions

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I am confused about some Qt architecture.

When I am designing the GUI in Qt Designer it is easy to put the elements in a layout (Grid, Box, what ever) and create a slot to connect elements (e.g. buttons) with a certain and action not much code in .cpp file.

In the related .cpp file I can access theses elements via `ui->element->do_something` even from different functions within the class;

When not using the designer, instead creating the whole GUI stuff within the .cpp (adding element objects, add those objects to a layout, creating a slot, etc...) I cannot access my e.g. Button like `ui->Button->do_something`.

I am stuck at `ui->Layout->functions from layout` and cannot access the single elements and their functions like `ui->textEdit->text();` or like `ui->Layout->textEdit->text()` from other functions within the class.

So how can I access those elements?

I am afraid I am missing an important point of Qt's architecture here or something else.

Comment: When you use (refer) an _object_ .. That object must be clearly defined/scoped  in your code .. `ui` is an object .. so what is it .. where did it come from? try to explore a qt example and trace its _objects_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use designer, an "Ui" file is auto-generated with the code of your layout, then you access through the Ui::Mainwindow which you can see auto-generated in your QMainWindow class.

You can see in the default constructor:

```
QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

So each component defined in the gui file is accessible through ui::nameofyourcomponent.

If you write the code manually you don't have any "access point" to your element so you have to build your hierarchy exactly like each other part of your code and classes.

Edit: A little snippet to answer to his comment.

In you header you can declare:

```
private slots:
void doSomething();

private:
QPushButton* mybutton;
QLabel* mylabel;
```

in your Cpp:

```
connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(doSomething) );

MyClass::doSomething()
{
   mylabel->setText("hello button!");
}
```

Of course you can use the connect chaining directly the components through their signal and slot.

Comment: ok so something like `connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this, SLOT(on_pushButton_action(pointer to element)));` and than declaring a function with some action to the GUI element from the pointer would do the job? Not really sure how I can create that hierarchy by my self otherwise.

Comment: I edited the answer addign a snippet of what you're asking. I added there because of better formatting.

Comment: `mylabel->setText("hello button!");`

Answer (score 1):

All of the objects the designer creates are public members of the `ui` object, that's why you can use them. To be able to use a manually created object, you have to store a pointer or reference to it somewhere.